# Breeze.js EntityManager not detecting changes

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, breeze

My viewmodel is as follows, bound to my page using knockout.js. Episodes is an array of entities, each with a boolean property 'ListenedTo' bound to a checkbox on my page.

```
function episodesViewModel() {

    this.episodes = ko.observableArray();

    this.sync = function () {
        repository.populateEpisodes(this);
    }

    this.save = function () {
        repository.saveChanges();
    }

    //this.episodes.subscribe(function (episodes) {
    //    ko.utils.arrayForEach(episodes, function (episode) {
    //        episode.ListenedTo.subscribe(function () {
    //            window.repository.saveChanges();
    //        });
    //    });
    //});

    // perform an initial sync
    this.sync();   
}
```

The repository object is just a wrapper for the underlying Breeze calls.

If I bind save() to a button click, everything works as expected, breeze sees there is changes and calls back to the server. If I uncomment the lines creating a subscription to the ListenedTo change (and saving without the need to click a button) then weird things happen.

After the page loads and is populated, the first click on the checkbox automatically calls breeze saveChanges() as expected. Even though the value in the viewmodel is as expected and matches the checkbox, breeze hasChanges() returns false and no server call is made. Click it again and hasChanges is now true and a server call is made!? It's like Breeze is lagging behind and doesn't register the change to the entities on the viewmodel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Oh my. Big trouble in your code! Before delving into details, what leaps off the page is the likelihood that you are adding subscriptions repeatedly to every episode in the `episodes` array every time that array changes. YIKES!

### Event propagation delays

Before I go on about my misgivings, I want to acknowledge your specific experience of inconsistency between when your listener fires and the value of `manager.hasChanges`. That's real. The KO subscription is firing before the `EntityManager` has heard about the change ... which is why it reports false. The news of the change has not yet arrived for the manager to hear.

I've noticed this too. In fact, if you look at the *viewModel.js* in the [TodoSample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-knockout), you'll see that we worked around it by adding a `setTimeout` to give Breeze a chance to hear the change:

```
// listen for changes with Breeze PropertyChanged event
item.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(function () {
    if (suspendItemSave) { return; }
    // give EntityManager time to hear the change
    setTimeout(saveIfModified, 0);

    function saveIfModified() {
        if (item.entityAspect.entityState.isModified()) {
                dataservice.saveChanges();
        }
    }
});
```

I wish I knew another way. That's just a timing problem between KO and Breeze. We haven't figured out how to finesse it yet. Not sure we'll be able to.

### Model rule or View rule?

Let's back up. Is the `episode` supposed to save when its `listenedTo` property changes **no matter what View it appears in?**  If your answer is "yes", then you have an application business rule that truly does belong in the model and you really do want something listening for episode changes.

But if the answer is "no" ... if the save should be triggered by the "checkbox", not a change to the object, then this is a UI rule ... a View rule ... and you should use KO to listen to the **checkbox**, not to the episode property.

### Saving when an entity changes

Let's go with the first case and assert that your application rule is as follows: "*always save when `listenedTo` changes, no matter what causes it to change*".

I know in the [TodoSample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-knockout) we demonstrated a way to listen directly to the entity for changes to one of its properties (any of its properties). That's powerful and it's intuitive.

I've come to believe that it is not the safest way. It has the potential for memory leaks in apps with multiple ViewModels that share the same entity. This "Todo" app has only one screen so that's not a real worry. But in a larger app ... I'd be concerned.

So I'm recommending against listening for changes to an `Episode` property. Instead **listen to the `EntityManager`!**  Look at this snippet from the *datacontext.js* in the recently released [Breeze SPA template](http://www.breezejs.com/spa-template).

```
function configureManagerToSaveModifiedItemImmediately() {
    manager.entityChanged.subscribe(entityStateChanged);
    
    function entityStateChanged(args) {
        if (args.entityAction === breeze.EntityAction.EntityStateChange) {
            var entity = args.entity;
            if (entity.entityAspect.entityState.isModified()) {
                saveEntity(entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how it listens for a state change in any entity that the EntityManager caches. It is  interested only in transitions to the "Modified" state. When detected, it saves the entity.

Now this may be too broad for you. But you can imagine registering extra filtering logic that fits the specific needs of your application.

### SaveQueuing

New issue having to do with auto-saving. This issue is important no matter how you trigger the save.

The user can click pretty fast. She is bound to trigger save requests faster than they can be processed. Breeze (by default) won't let an `EntityManager` save again while it is waiting for the server to return results from a pending save operation. It will throw an exception.

It has to wait because it can't change the state of the entity from changed to unchanged until it knows if the save was successful. If the save fails, you want to keep the entity in its "unsaved" state.

Look at the top of the *datacontext.js* for `manager.enableSaveQueuing(true)`. This is **not** a native feature of breeze. It's a feature of a plugin, *Scripts/breeze.savequeuing.js*   You'll want to load this plugin. Read about it in the write up for the [Breeze SPA template](http://www.breezejs.com/spa-template)

### Why so complicated

You might think **this Breeze thing is mighty complicated**. Actually, it's not Breeze that's introducing the complication. It's your desire to trigger a save when the entity changes its state that is adding the complications.

I'm not saying you're wrong to do so. I am saying that this approach is an opportunity afforded by Breeze that takes some care in its implementation.

Without Breeze, you'd have a devil of a time tracking the entity state at all. So your only really safe option would be to trigger the save based on a change to the checkbox ... in which case the effort is no more complicated than a KO binding to the checkbox.

Well ... ok ... it is a little more complicated due to the Breeze/KO timing problem that you tripped over which necessitate the`setTimeout` gambit. But I hope you see my point.

Comment: Great answer thanks. This app only has a single view to modify this particular entity so I may resort to the timeout fix. It's difficult to say whether this piece of logic is part of the domain model or the view when there is only a single view modifying the entity! The domain model (in my mind) only exists serverside. The entity Breeze manages is just a DTO.  

Slightly offtopic but does anyone know how to correct my subscribe code? JS is all new to me.

Comment: I understand when you say "*The domain model (in my mind) only exists serverside. The entity Breeze manages is just a DTO.*"  Yes, the server (storage and business logic) is the "single source of truth". That's important. On the other hand, I urge you to think of your stateful, SPA application client as having a domain model of its own. Its "domain context" reflects the "meaning" of the model *on the client* as experienced by the user. Clearly the model on the client is more than a DTO ... more than a bag of data. It's a different domain than the server, but a domain nonetheless.

Comment: Unfortunately I seem to have accepted this a little prematurely. The timeout statement doesn't seem to resolve the issue for me. HasChanges is still false, even after increasing the timeout value. I thought about your comments re. subscribing to the EntityManager's property change notification instead and this actually seemed to make more sense. The problem here is, I change the checkbox bound to the ListenedTo property and for some reason Breeze told me 3 properties had changed even though old/new values were shown to be the same.

Comment: The length of the timeout is immaterial (as you discovered). I use a timeout of zero in this scenario myself. It the timeout didn't cure the problem, something else is amiss. I think you will have to show us (a) the pertinent HTML markup and (b) the corresponding ViewModel bindings. Try to keep is short :)

Comment: I think I'm going to stay subscribing to entityAspect.propertyChanged. It seems calling saveChanges() will register as 2 properties changing unexpectedly. One called null. The other is my 'Date' property which seems to have matching old/new values. Why is save registering these properties as changes?

Comment: When a property changes, Breeze captures the old and current values. Breeze does NOT care if you change the current value back to the old value; once changed ... it's changed. Why don't we detect that they are the same? Well ... because equality checks get complicated quickly. YOU know that the values are the same. But there are subtleties in value comparison that we decided to avoid. Maybe we'll tackle that in future, allowing you to specify an equality function in metadata. But that feature is for another day.

Comment: I understand this. I don't understand why calling saveChanges itself triggers the change event with 2 properties supposedly showing changes. My Date property for example isn't even bound to a control on the view but supposedly changes when saveChanges is called.

Comment: Are you saying that (1) the date property is changed *after you save* the entity or (2) *after you save*, the entity is still in a changed state?  #2 would indicate a failed save. #1 is possible if your server/database updated that property before returning it to the client. For example, suppose the property is a database-maintained `ModifiedDate`. You save a change to the `Name` property, the db trigger updates the `ModifiedDate`, Breeze Web API returns the updated entity to the client, the client sees the date change, & updates the UI. The `EntityState` is "Unchanged". Perfectly normal.

Comment: (1) The entity is put in a modified state after saveChanges(). Even if I remove the Date property from my serverside model I still see a property called 'null' as changed. Looking at the SaveResult on my C# WebApi BreezeController, I can't see why it would return in a modified state.

Comment: It can't ... you're dreaming :)   Honestly, though, this makes no sense to me. Are you doing anything to the returned data? Do you have an initializer (not that that should matter because it's supposed to be called before the manager "accepts changes" and transitions the EntityState to "Unchanged". You may have to make a small sample and post it to GitHub or something like that. Sorry for your pains.

Comment: https://github.com/thecapsaicinkid/shoryuken/blob/master/spa/PodcastTest/Scripts/app/episodeRepository.js

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know without more information (e.g. what other frameworks are used, what triggers the VM instantiation code, where is the KO.ApplyBind)
Is your view properly constructed at the time the VM is created?

I am now using Durandal which creates the VM first, then the view. Attempts to create addtional subscriptions during Durandal's activate event (or earlier like your instantiation code), resulted in KO view/viewModel subscriptions being disposed as they are found to be invalid. I had to create my subscriptions in Durandal's later viewAttached event

Try putting your subscribes later in the workflow.